# Weird behavior when downloading html using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

In my Wikipedia reader app for Android, I'm downloading an article's html by using HttpURLConnection, some users report that they are unable to see articles, instead they see some css, so it seems like their carrier is somehow preprocessing the html before it's downloaded, while other wikipedia readers seem to work fine.

Example url: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Moon_(album)

My method:

```
public static String downloadString(String url) throws Exception
{
    StringBuilder downloadedHtml = new StringBuilder(); 

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;

    try
    {
        URL targetUrl = new URL(url);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();

        if (url.toLowerCase().contains("/special"))
            urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        else
            urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        //read the result from the server
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            downloadedHtml.append(line + '\n');
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        AppLog.e("An exception occurred while downloading data.\r\n: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (urlConnection != null)
        {
            AppLog.i("Disconnecting the http connection");
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        if (rd != null)
            rd.close();
    }

    return downloadedHtml.toString();
}
```

I'm unable to reproduce this problem, but there must be a way to get around that? I even disabled redirects by setting setInstanceFollowRedirects to 'false' but it didn't help.

Am I missing something?

Example of what the users are reporting:

http://pastebin.com/1E3Hn2yX

Comment: @onkar How can it be related to lost data packets? the CSS is not supposed to be loaded from that url. It has nothing to do with lost packets.

Comment: From exception handling point of view this code is suboptimal. Maybe you also swallow exceptions or take the risk of producing exceptions in `finally` in your main code and observe strange effects because of that.

Comment: @hgoebl I have other types of checks before that method is called so the code is not suboptimal, and I don't see how I take any risks of producing exceptions in the 'finally' clause. The html is downloaded without any exceptions, it's most likely related to a proxy or some data saving app that is modifying the html.

Comment: Remove `throws Exception` from your method and you'll see.

Comment: @hgoebl ... I already told you before, no exception is thrown. So how is 'throws Exception' related, what am I supposed to see?

Comment: @MaryJ. Your code is most certainly sub-optimal. Using  `throws Exception` instead of more specific sub class is a big no-no in Java. Doing that completely bypasses the point of the `throws` declaration in the first place. And catching `Exception` is just as bad. That said, i doubt your problem has anything to do with exceptions. It's probably more to do with what the program receives from that URL. Can you try to capture the content (including headers) and have it sent to you in a bug report?

Comment: Another interesting question would be: Is the code following any redirects?

Comment: @RoToRa it shouldn't be, see: urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> carrier is somehow preprocessing the html before it's downloaded
>
> a way to get around that?

Use HTTPS to prevent carriers from rewriting pages. (no citation)

> Am I missing something?

not that I can see

Comment: What was the result @Mary J ? Was the problem solved by using https?

Comment: @bgth yes, it did actually help :)